# Select / subset spatial data in R

Tags: r, dictionary, spatial

I am working on a large data set with spatial data (lat/long). My data set contains some positions that I don´t want in my analysis (it makes the files to heavy to process in ArcMap- many Go of data).

This is why I want to subset the relevant data for my work. Here is an example of my data:

```
lat        long
59.979687  29.706236
60.136177  28.148186
59.331383  22.376234
57.699154  11.667305
54.90566   17.768538
57.122417  8.59762
55.8108    10.820534
57.86072   22.616697
59.912144  30.24504
```

The data I have are from all of the area covered in the following map. I would like to work only on the Baltic Sea, so (almost) only with the points on the left of this dark line.
[image: map]

Does someone heard about a package or has some ideas about how to deal with this?

An other solution might be to drawn a polygon around the Baltic Sea and only to select the points within this polygon.

Comment: [This site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) is dedicated to such a question. However, have a look at function `over` from `sp` package. And there is a problem with line 8 of your sample data.

Comment: do some algebra. Take any two coordinates on the black line and you can filter out everything above or below it. Can you provide two points on the separating line that you'd like?

Comment: Is that line part of a great circle or a straight line in lat-long degrees or some other coordinates system? But drawing a polygon and using `over` is probably the solution, see the R Spatial Task View for more on this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! @plafort, here are two points X1: lat 69,91 long 23,07 and for X2; lat 57,98 and long is 7,05.

Comment: @Spacedman, the line is a straight line. I will have a look to the R Spatial Task View.

Comment: Hard to find... some packages (point in polygons) are not working with R3.2...

Comment: @Spacedman `sp::point.in.polygon` may be sufficient for OP's needs. OP: see answer which clearly shows `point.in.polygon` is far from broken.

Comment: @Floni the earth isn't flat so a "straight line" on a map can be a number of things depending on the map projection. I don't really think its a problem here since you just want to cut out the Baltic Sea, but you need to be precise if its a precise problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going with the assumption you meant "to the right" since you said *"Another solution might be to drawn a polygon around the Baltic Sea and only to select the points within this polygon"*

```
# your sample data

pts <- read.table(text="lat        long
59.979687  29.706236
60.136177  28.148186
59.331383  22.376234
57.699154  11.667305
54.90566   17.768538
57.122417  8.59762
55.8108    10.820534
57.86072   22.616697
59.912144  30.24504", header=TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

# a rough baltic polygon that I deliberately made to exclude one point

baltic <- data.frame(lat=c(69.91, 57.98, 51.0, 60, 69.91),
                     long=c(23.07, 7.05, 12.0, 30, 23.07))

# only doing this to show the points, you can filter out in similar fashion

pts$is_in <- factor(point.in.polygon(pts$long, pts$lat, baltic$long, baltic$lat))

# I made an _extremely_ oversimplified map of europe for speedy plotting
europe <- readOGR("http://rud.is/dl/simple_europe.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
europe_map <- fortify(europe)


# plot to show it works
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=europe_map, data=europe_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="white", color="black", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=pts, aes(x=long, y=lat, color=is_in))
gg <- gg + geom_path(data=baltic, (aes(x=long, y=lat)), linetype=2)

# lambert isn't a bad projection for the region
gg <- gg + coord_map("lambert", lat0=50, lat1=70, xlim=c(5,31), ylim=c(50, 70))
gg
```

[image]

You can make the polygon as big as you need to get the points you want to include. Remember, I made it just small enough to exclude that one "red" point on purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The beginning is really good. I don´t know why but I could not used point.in.polygon. Now it is working. Thanks!